# GIF loading stops when I show it

Tags: jquery, loading, gif, animated-gif

Look this code:

```
$('#loader').show();
$.post( '/action.php', function( data ) {  
// do anything with data
$('#loader').hide(); 
}  );
```

The loader DIV has a GIF image simulating loading state, This code works well but the GIF stops when is waiting the data (post called) ...

I want the gif moves ever independently of the other codes in execution.. I hope you understand my problem..

Comment: what browser? any? I've seen such behaviour with IE, however ajaxStart, ajaxStop and ajaxError work fine for me.

Comment: Duplicate of: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191413/why-does-my-spinner-gif-stop-while-jquery-ajax-call-is-running - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping Both contain workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want the behavior listed in the example on the jQuery documentation website.

[jQuery:ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

You can hide the image with the ajaxStop event handler.