# What are advantages of returning Javascript objects from Server Side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, server-side, serverside-javascript

I see that most of big websites are returning javascript objects instead of pure HTML output, and renders it client side.

What are the advantages of using this approach? (and I think they are when used by Google, FB and others).

I think that one of the advantages is that it doesn't "freezes" the browser when inserting new html into the page. [Freeze problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191413/why-does-my-spinner-gif-stop-while-jquery-ajax-call-is-running)

Also is it easy to transfer / process it if you have a good javascript API.

Do you know others?

[image: Javascript Objects Return]

Comment: An ajax request won't freeze the browser while waiting on the server to respond with the data, but any process which writes to the DOM will 'freeze' the browser while the new content is being added. Not sure if this is what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, i mean at the process of inserting a lot of HTML into DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the [JSON data format](http://json.org/), not JavaScript objects (although the syntax is compatible).

JSON is:

- Lightweight
- Structured
- Well supported by libraries for just about every programming language out there

> instead of pure HTML output

The particular example you give has embedded HTML. Presumably the request is for more then a single piece of content to insert into a single part of the page.

Comment: The key of using this principle would be of using POCO objects in you're application (so they are serialized)?

Comment: I've not come across the term "POCO" before, it seems to be a .NET term. The point of JSON is that it lets you express a hierarchical data structure, using a set of data types that are common to most programming languages so converting to and from JSON is trivial in most environments.

Comment: @RaraituL The term "POCO" only applies to the .NET context and not to the likes of html/javascript http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object also `Plain Old CLR Object Object` just sounds wrong.