# gif animation stops when appending data

Tags: jquery

Data is received from ajax request.
BeforeSend an animated gif preloader is shown.
On ajax success preloader is turned off and response is appended to a div (jQuery append).

The problem is following: when html starts building animation freezes on one frame.
Preloader doesn't turn off even if code is placed before appening response data. It just freezes and looks like waits for it to finish.

Is there a workaround this issue?

P.S.:
added some code to make it clearer for those that haven't understood from text:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: '',
    url: 'ajax_script.php',
    beforeSend : function() {
        $('.add_element_preloader').css('visibility', 'visible');  
    },
    success: function(response){                    
        $('.add_element_preloader').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('.container').append(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: What about posting relevant code in question???

Comment: I have no idea if this is relevant to jQuery at all

Comment: You don't need a code here. It just basic stuff.

Comment: @YorickdeWid
I had the same idea. That this is some browser issue because it's building new html-code it stops playing animation. But I hoped that there is a way to just turn it off.

Comment: What does the browser console say?

Comment: `append()` is sync as all updating DOM methods, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191413/why-does-my-spinner-gif-stop-while-jquery-ajax-call-is-running  So if your response is too big, this is expected behaviour

Comment: @YorickdeWid Nothing at all. And I just noticed that if I leave preloader on all the time it freezes just at time of getting response and building new structure with it.

Comment: @A.Wolff :)))) Your link says that problem is in browser because its UI is single threaded. But, yep, looks like this is the problem. With a lot of new structure building looks like it stops everything.
I just don't get one thing. I try to turn off preloader before it starts appending new code - but it doesn't turn off.

Comment: @user3725355 I guess because no redraw is called on UI, try to force UI redraw to check it, e.g, try: `$('.add_element_preloader').css('visibility', 'hidden');document.body.offsetHeight;$('.container').append(response);`

Comment: @A.Wolff same problem. Animation freezes on one frame and disappears only when appending finished.