# Sluggish animation on DOM change

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe, youtube

Imagine that i have a **constant animation running**, rather it be css, javascript, or in this case for the sake of simplicity a .gif file, and then i **append to the DOM** a "heavy" element like a youtube iframe and the constant animation get **sluggish** for a second.

Is there any straightforward or workaround way to achieve such DOM change **without staggering the animation?**

In the example below notice that if you change the iframe for yet another gif or even one iframe with a fairly simple website the animation runs without staggering or getting sluggish.

Demo/Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbdewR

stackoverflow is throwing a warning that links to codepen.io must be accompanied with code, it is my first time posting so i hope this is what it is asked for:

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
  // Sluggish
  $('.video-container').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FprQEGc3Za4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

  // Not Sluggish
  //$('.video-container').html('<img src="http://media2.giphy.com/media/e7FOBuKCDtwWI/giphy.gif"/>');

  // Not Sluggish
  //$('.video-container').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://html5doctor.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://media.giphy.com/media/lRBEntSxN87WE/giphy.gif" alt="" />
<div class="video-container">
  <a class="button" href='#'>wait for the gif to load completely and press me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: there is only one main thread per tab, and both dom re-layout and gif animations use it. some video may be hardware accelerated, but loading it will likely always slow down the rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no solution to your problem... It is a matter of web browsers.

This post may help you: [Why does my spinner GIF stop while jQuery ajax call is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191413/why-does-my-spinner-gif-stop-while-jquery-ajax-call-is-running)

Answer (score 0):

Loading an iframe is going to cause massive delay with loading, layout and DOM changes.

You may be able to decrease some of that impact by making the iframe display: none until it's needed, then rendering it with display: block .. not sure if you have enough control over the iframe video to be able to make it not autoplay even if it's invisible, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following :

write the html code for your iframe with style as display : none

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FprQEGc3Za4" frameborder="0" style="display:none;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and when you click the button then the code js code should be :

```
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
    $('iframe').css('display','block');
});
```

in this way your gif file won't be sluggish.

Comment: Nope, that does not work the staggering still happens with the display none, same fix that @eric-blade mentioned